# Why use a closure for assignment instead of directly assigning a value to a key?

Tags: php, closures, variable-assignment

I was watching [this video](https://youtu.be/70IkLMkPyPs?list=PLfdtiltiRHWGc_yY90XRdq6mRww042aEC&t=432) and at 7:10 he's adding a db dependency and is using a closure to assign the value.

My question is why not just use direct assignment instead, I mean isn't doing this:

```
$container['db'] = $capsule;
```

equivalent to doing this:

```
$container['db'] = function ($container) use ($capsule) {
    return $capsule;
}
```

If not, what is the difference and which way is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR** it's because defining dependencies as closures makes it possible for dependency injection container to build them on demand, hence you don't need to worry about their order of definition and managing their dependencies manually.

Pimple is **Dependency Injection Container**, it is supposed to help you set up your objects by managing their dependencies in an easy and convenient way.

If you directly assign a value to a key, Pimple calls that value a **parameter**, and when you need to access that key, it simply returns that exact value:

```
$container['sample-param'] = 'foo';
echo $container['sample-param'];
//output: foo
```

But the point is, this `sample-param` does not require any set up, it is simply a value and we're fine with that. But assume the following service setup:

```
$container['myService'] = function($c) {
    $service = new \Some\Complicated\Service();
    //this service depends on cache service
    $service->setCache($c['cache']);
    return $service;
}

$container['cache'] = function($c) {
    $cache = new \Cache\Driver();
    //our cache driver needs a db connection
    $cache->setDbConnection($c['db']);
    return $cache;
}

$container['db'] = function($c) {
    //our database connection requires some parameters
    $dbConnection = new \Database\Connection($c['db-config']);
    return $dbConnection;
}

$container['db-config'] = [
    'username' => 'foo',
    'password' => 'bar',
    'host' => 'localhost'
];

//Now we want to user our service:
$container['myService']->doSomething();
```

Please pay attention to order which I used to define different keys in the container.

`myService` needs `cache` but cache definition comes after myService definition. And this is where Pimple is helping, and this is why we pass container to every closure, because Pimple is going to **build our dependencies on demand**. When we need to access `myService` Pimple looks at its internal data storage, if it has previously built and stored `myService` successfully, it will return that same instance, else it will call our closure to build it. And when our closure is called, it will ask Pimple ($c is the Pimple container) to give it its **dependecies** (which in this case is the `cache` service). Pimple applies the same thing on cache, if it is not built yet, it will build it and so on...till it gets to the part that requires simple params like `db-config` which will immediately return. And in this chain of closure calls, our object and all its dependencies are built.

Now imagine what would happen if we used simple values instead of closures? In that case, when we want to build `myService` **we** have to take care of its dependencies. We have to make sure its dependencies are defined **before** we define the service itself and **we** have to deal with other problems related to managing dependencies. In that case we couldn't just define our `myService` and *assume* there is a `cache` service available, which will be defined later.

Answer (score 0):

In that video he is using Slim framework for the container which by default is using Pimple for it's container.

http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/

In the documentation on that page it mentions the following

> Defining Services A service is an object that does something as part
> of a larger system. Examples of services: a database connection, a
> templating engine, or a mailer. Almost any global object can be a
> service.
>
> Services are defined by anonymous functions that return an instance of
> an object:
>
> ```
> // define some services
> $container['session_storage'] = function ($container) {
>     return new SessionStorage('SESSION_ID');
> };
>
> $container['session'] = function ($container) {
>     return new Session($container['session_storage']);
> };
> ```
>
> Notice that the anonymous function has access to the current container instance, allowing references to other services or parameters.

By design the containers expect to call a function

Pimple's containers implement the `\ArrayAccess` interface [(seen here)](https://github.com/silexphp/Pimple/blob/master/src/Pimple/Container.php), and that means they can make the object act like an array while not necessarily being one. In the source code you'll notice `offsetSet` and `offsetGet`, which are what happens when you do:

```
$container['a'] = function($c){ return new Blah();}

$thing = $container['a'];
```

**tl;dr** It's a Pimple container specific thing, not a PHP specific thing.