# Pimple ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function

Tags: php, dependency-injection, psr-4, pimple

I'm trying to understand dependency injection, and I in theory, I get it, but, I wanted to make an example just to help me. However, I'm getting the following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Main\Services\UserService::__construct(), 0 passed
in ...
```

Here's my "main" file, I've called it *index.php*

```
<?php 
#index.php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Main\Controllers\UserController;
use Main\Services\UserService;
use Main\Models\UserModel;
use Pimple\Container;

$container = new Container;
$container['UserModel'] = function($c) {
    return new UserModel();
};

$container['UserService'] = function ($c) {
    return new UserService($c['UserModel']);
};

$container['UserController'] = function ($c) {
    echo "creating a new UserController\n";

    $aUserService = $c['UserService'];
    return new UserController($aUserService);
};

$myUserService = new $container['UserService'];
$myResult = $myUserService->parseGet();
echo $myResult, PHP_EOL;
```

Here's the *model* that's being passed into the service

```
<?php
# Models/UserModel.php
namespace Main\Models;

class UserModel
{
    private $record;

    public function getRecord()
    {
        return [
            'first_name' => 'Bob',
            'last_name'  => 'Jones',
            'email'      => 'bj@example.com',
            'date_joined' => '11-12-2014',
        ];
    }
}
```

And, here's the service, which takes the model as it's constructor argument

```
<?php
namespace Main\Services;

use Main\Models\UserModel;

class UserService
{
    private $userModel;

    public function __construct(UserModel $userModel)
    {
        echo "verifying that the userModel passed in was a valid UserModel\n";
        $this->userModel = $userModel;

         print_r($this->userModel->getRecord());
    }

    public function parseGet()
    {
        $retVal = $this->userModel->getRecord();

        return json_encode($retVal);
    }
}
```

So, in theory, Pimple should be able to instantiate a *UserService* object. I even verified that the *UserModel* passed into the *UserService* class is a valid *UserModel* object (which it is as is evident that it prints out an array)

What am I missing? Is there something that I have failed to account for?

Oh, here's the composer.json file

```
{
    "require": {
        "pimple/pimple": "~3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Main\\" : "./"
        }
    }
}
```

I made a gitHub link so the project can be checked out and ran without having to copy past everything (https://github.com/gitKearney/pimple-example)

### SOLUTION

The problem was I have an extra *new* in the line

```
$myUserService = new $container['UserService'];
```

It was so obvious, I couldn't see it

Comment: Good work adding the repro case to Github, btw. Was really helpful being able to grab yer code and run it.

Comment: Of course! Anything to help you help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$container['UserService']` already *is* a UserService object. check yer service definition:

```
$container['UserService'] = function ($c) {
    return new UserService($c['UserModel']);
};
```

That sets `$container['UserService']` to be `return new UserService($c['UserModel'])` when it's invoked, right?

Your code is basically going:

```
$o1 = new UserService($c['UserModel']);
$o2 = new $o2;
```

Comment: OMG! It was so simple! I have an extra "new" in front of 

    $myUserService = $container['UserService'];

Answer (score 0):

You use dependency injection containers to free yourself form the pain of manipulating objects' dependencies. Creating a new `UserService` is not necessary (*if it really is a service*). In that case, you define it in your `$container` once, and use it whenever you need to.

So instead of creating a new `UserService` object and calling its method `parseGet()` (what you did in your code) you can do something like this:

```
$myResult = $container['UserService']->parseGet();
```

When you define something like:

```
$container['UserService'] = function ($c) {
    return new UserService($c['UserModel']);
};
```

**you are telling Pimple how to handle creation of a UserService once you try to access $container['UserService']**

That's why you define dependencies as functions.

This might be related to your question [Why use a closure for assignment instead of directly assigning a value to a key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627339/why-use-a-closure-for-assignment-instead-of-directly-assigning-a-value-to-a-key/45535994#45535994)

Comment: ah! Thanks! The example I gave wasn't a "real world" example. I was having a problem, and the error made no sense to me. The line of code should be *$myUserController = $container['UserController'];*

Comment: Yes it should (or `$myUserService = $container['UserService']` to be more like your example).